# SQL select row containing all of the values in interval

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, entity-relationship

I know the question is poorly worded, I'm sorry, I can't really put this problem into words. Here is a representation:

I have two tables: product and availability. A product can have multiple dates when it's available. Example:

```
Table 1 (products):
id     | name              | ....
----------------------------------
1      | My product 1      | ....
2      | My product 2      | ....


Table 2 (availability):
id     | productId         | date
-----------------------------------------
1      | 1                 | 2021-01-15
2      | 1                 | 2021-01-16
3      | 1                 | 2021-01-17
4      | 2                 | 2021-01-15
5      | 2                 | 2021-01-16
```

Is there an sql statement that, given an interval, allows us to fetch a list of products having a row in the availabilty table for each element of the interval?

For example, given the interval [2021-01-15 -> 2021-01-17], the request should return product 1 because it's available during the entire period (it has a row for each element: the 15th, 16th and 17th). Product2 isn't returned because it's not available on 2021-01-17.

Is there a way to do this in SQL or do I have to use PL/SQL?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: What is an "element of the interval"?  Nothing in your data is called "element".

Comment: I've mentioned it in the example paragraph, sorry if it's unclear. The interval is [2021-01-15 -> 2021-01-17], so the elements would be 2021-01-15, 2021-01-16 and 2021-01-17

Comment: . . "date" <> "element".  Also, you have tagged with two databases (SQL Server and Oracle implicitly via PL/SQL).  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, came up with this, thanks @Popeye for the inspiration.

```
select occurence.pid from
(
    select a.product_id as pid, count(distinct a.date::date) as cnt
            from availability a
            where a.date >= '2021-01-15'
                and a.date < '2021-01-17'::date + 1
            group by a.product_id
) as occurence
where cnt = '2021-01-17'::date - '2021-01-15'::date + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select p.* from
(select p.*, count(distinct a.date) over (partition by a.productid) as cnt
  from products p
  join availability a on a.productid = p.id
 where a.date >= date '201-01-15'
  and  a.date < date '201-01-17' + 1  )
where cnt = date '201-01-17' - date '201-01-15' + 1
```

Comment: Implementing this function didn't give me any errors (I had to change some syntax like: '2021-01-17'::date - '2021-01-15'::date + 1). However on executing it, I get: "DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions". Any ideas?